# data structure for python and reportlabs charts

Tags: python, list, reportlab

Admittedly I think I may be stumped because i can't figure out how to describe my problem so I can effectively google it...

in short the report lab horizontal line chart I'm trying to create works when I assign data to my list variable when I build it like this:

```
data=[(55,56,57,58)]
```

or (after carefully reading the report lab documentation for a single series chart
    data=[(55,56,57,58),]

However, the *lists* that i'm building in my python code come out like the this
    data=[55, 56, 57, 58]

So what is the difference between [#, #, #] and [(#, #, #)]

Answer (score 2):

- `[#,#,#]` is a list
- `(#,#,#)` is a tuple
- `[(#,#,#)]` is a (one element) list of a tuple

Comment: thx, after more read I concluded that since I am incrementally building my data in a list I will need to build my list and use it to build the single element tuple by the following:

single_element_tuple=tuple([list])